# Convert html, pdf or .doc format to google doc without breaking formatting

Tags: pdf, conversion, html, documents, google-docs

I'm building some documents which need to live online on google docs.  I start off by building static html files using Ruby on Rails.  These look fine.

Then I convert them to a pdf using `wkhtmltopdf`.  These also look fine.

Then, i convert them to .doc files using `https://pdf2doc.com/`.  These look mostly fine.

The problem comes when I want to get them on google docs in an editable format.  If I import either the .pdf or the .doc. and choose 'convert into google doc', the formatting is completely broken.  Like totally all over the place: images jumbled up next to each other etc.

I've tried a chrome extension called "Save to Google Drive", which can be called on the html version, but that looks awful as well.

One approach I haven't tried is to output all of the data used to build the docs (there are about 10 docs to build, all with an identical format but different data) into a google spreadsheet and do some kind of mail merge thing to generate the docs.  But it feels like there must be a way to make either a google doc OR a google slideshow out of either html, pdf or .doc format without the format getting messed up.

Another thing i thought of was to try and build the original html files just using tables, to see if they make it through the translation process better.  But again, lots of hassle.

Any advice, anyone?

**EDIT** - it occurred to me that maybe I need to set a particular doctype, or some meta tags, in my html?  Is that likely?

Comment: There exist HTML to DOCX converters, have you tried some?

Comment: Did you try pandoc for conversion?

Comment: @harrymc i googled for this but either didn't find any or couldn't find one that did a good job (I can't remember now, sorry) - if you're able to recommend one that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Destroy666 I did try Pandoc but the results were terrible.  I wasn't sure if I was using it correctly though.  Do you think that a doc (or docx?) made with pandoc would upload to google docs more nicely?  The actual doc files that I have made look fine when opened with Open Office or Pages.

Comment: There are several found in google [html to docx](https://www.google.fr/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hl=en-FR&gbv=1&q=html+to+docx&oq=&aqs=).

Comment: @harrymc yes i've tried a few of those, they all break the formatting.  I'm going to try doing it as tables.

Comment: What in the formatting breaks? Why are you going that convoluted route, through all those conversions? Every step of this process seems to beg "why?" I think it may be a good idea to step back and reconsider what each step is accomplishing, and whether there's a better way to do that. If you can step back in your question and explain these Why's, that may also help us help you to a better overall solution.

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details and some of the details are unclear. .doc is not the same as .docx . Consider to use the Google Docs API to create the documents directly in Google Docs. Also the question looks to need more focus.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what might be happening. Please bear in mind that Google Docs doesn't support all the stuff that can be done with "HTML" and that Google Drive has limits. From [Files you can store in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)

> #### File sizes
>
> The following are the maximum file sizes you can store in Google Drive:
>
> ##### Documents
>
> Up to 1.02 million characters.
> If you convert a text document to Google Docs format, it can be up to 50 MB.

Try creating a document using only simple HTML tags with no attributes. Omit the use of `div`, `iframe`, `video`, `audio`, `form`, `input`, `select`, `textarea`, `img`, and `span` tags. There might be others to omit. Review that all the tags that properly closed.

You might tables (`table`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tr`, `th`, and `td`) to handle the layout but assure that there is no table that exceeds the page size that you will use in Google Docs. Don't forget that Google Docs has default page settings.

Once you confirm that the basic document structure is being converted correctly add styling using inline CSS (style attribute), you might use `span` tags and add `img` tags.

Be sure that the images are hosted on the web, are publicly available, and each one is relatively small (less than 1 MB), and that the HTML and images size are less than 50 MB. If you need to use larger images, you could try to add them later directly into the corresponding document by using the Google Documents editor. It might be also possible to do this by using Google Apps Script and/or the Google Docs API.